# JDBC preparedStatement not working in JSP

Tags: jsp, jdbc, oracle11g, prepared-statement

1. PreparedStatement is working fine if query is static (no parameters), for example:

   ```
   select * from RWEMP;
   ```
2. but if I use the code below with a search condition:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM RWEMP WHERE ENAME= ?
   ```

   It doesn't show anything, it is just showing the table headers.

   ```
   <FORM METHOD="get"> 
           <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="cond" SIZE=50>
   </FORM> <br> <br>

       <% String value = request.getParameter("cond"); 
           if (value != null) { %>
       <H3> Search results for  <I> <%= value %> </I> </H3>
           <% }  %>

       <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>  
            <%Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

             String sql="SELECT * FROM RWEMP WHERE ENAME= ?";

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hari","root"); 
            PreparedStatement stat=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stat.setString(1,"value");
            ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery();
            try {
                if(rs!=null) {
            %>     
           <table border=1 cellspan=60 cellpadding=16> 
                <tr>
                   <th> Emp ID </th>
                   <th> Emp Name </th>
                   <th> Emp Dept </th>
                   <th> Emp Area </th>
                   <th> Emp D.O.B  </th>
                   <th> EMP Mobile </th>
                   <th> Emp Salary </th>
                   <th> EMP Wife </th>
               </tr> 
           <%
             while(rs.next()) {
           %>
           <tr> 
               <td><%= rs.getString("EID")%> </td>
               <td><%= rs.getString("ENAME") %> </td>
               <td><%= rs.getString("EDEPT")%> </td>
               <td><%= rs.getString("EAREA")%> </td>
               <td><%= rs.getString("EDOB")%> </td>
               <td><%= rs.getString("EMOBILE")%> </td>
               <td><%= rs.getString("ESAL")%> </td>
               <td><%= rs.getString("ESPOUSE")%> </td>
            </tr>
            <%
             } 
              }
        }                        
             catch(SQLException e) { 
               e.printStackTrace();
                } 
   con.close();
   ```

   %>

Comment: Unrelated, but: don't put SQL code like that inside a JSP - especially not obtaining a connection. Use a connection pool for that. The JSP should **only** contain presentation code, never Java code and absolutely never SQL code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `PreparedStatement`'s query parameter binding code as

```
stat.setString(1, value); // no quotes
```

You need to search on what the `value` variable contains, not by its name "value" itself.